# How do I render Big Buck Bunny in the year 2020?

Tags: rendering

I downloaded the .zip of project files for Big Buck Bunny (from http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/blender/ ).  There are 3 directories: 2d, 3d, post.  I loaded up 2d/00_00.blend into blender 2.79 for linux-glibc219-x86_64 and tried to Render>Render Image , but I got a solid white image.  I tried to render a frame from 01_01.blend and got a solid black image.

The .zip file included zero instructions.  I can not see anything like a Makefile.  Is there a web site with instructions on how to render Big Buck Bunny from the project files?